K8S Connaisseur to ArgoCD issues
I am a bit stumped here. There is an existing connaisseur setup deployed in my K8S cluster, and I am trying to get it to sync with argoCD. I do not want to recreate any resources; however, annotations that Argo adds is okay.
So far I have done the following, but still a bit stumped, and not sure where I am missing something. Apologies if this seems like a newbie thing or something, but I just haven't dug this deep into K8s manifests or argo before and would love insight/pointers.
kubectl get all -n <connaisseur namespace> -o connaisseur_manifest.yaml
anyways, I look into this, and decide, OK, let me try and template this so that argo syncs up with it.
for instance, the argo structure is set up like this:
/apps/connaisseur/<chart.yaml>,<values.yaml>,<env.yaml>, and templates/
in the templates directory is where the other charts live, configmap.yaml, deployment.yaml etc,.
then for the application set itself, I have that here /deploy/applicationsets/connaisseur/
which points at the files to be templated and deployed in the previous path mentioned that contains the template files.
I am also quite new to helm, so I'm unsure if I am approaching this the right way, especially in the context of connaisseur.
this is what I am using for reference: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/connaisseur/connaisseur?modal=template&template=configmaps.yaml
how can I properly translate into the templates, of what is currently deployed, so that argo simply syncs it, without destroying and recreating everything?
So far, I've tried to apply the templates from: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/connaisseur/connaisseur?modal=template&template=configmaps.yaml
while defining what my existing deployment contains in the values.yaml file. Argo populates the actual app deployment, but when it does its own 'helm template' nothing materializes from it. So I am assuming the translation of what my current setup is, doesn't carry over to the written YAML.
The idea is, to have environment specific yaml files, that simply contain 3 different values from the dev environment, to utilize the same template when argo deploys.
for example, dev.yaml: cluster: dev, cert: devert.crt, environment:dev would be all that's defined and the rest gets filled in with those values to deploy properly.
apologies if this whole thing makes no sense. I am sure I am not explaining it properly, and can provide more details once I know what to look for.
